# Characters added to end of string at run time

Tags: c#

I have a `bool` that checks to see if a local web service is available by testing a quick query, if it fails then `StartOSRMService()` is ran.

**Config:**

```
    Config config = new Config
    {
        localhostNearest = "C:/path/...",
        localhostRoute = "C:/path/...",
        processLocation = @"C:/path/...",
        WorkingDirectory = @"C:/path/...",
        DataSource = "file-latest.osrm"
    };
```

**StartOSRMService()**

```
    private void StartOSRMService()
    {
        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(config.processLocation);
        startInfo.WorkingDirectory = config.WorkingDirectory;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.Arguments = config.DataSource;
        Process.Start(startInfo);
    }
```

**ServiceAvailable():**

```
    public bool ServiceAvailable()
    {
        string lon = "-0.00000000";
        string lat = "51.0000000000";
        try
        {
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create($"{config.localhostNearest}{lon},{lat}");
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Routing point = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Routing>(responseFromServer);
            if (point.code == "Ok")
            {
                return true;
            }
            StartOSRMService();
            return false; // Needed but never executed?
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            StartOSRMService();
            // TODO receive routes?
            return false;
        }
    }
```

When `StartOSRMService()` is ran, I get this output:

```
[info] starting up engines, v5.3.0[0m
[info] Threads: 8[0m
[info] IP address: 0.0.0.0[0m
```

With `[0m` being appended to *everything* that comes out of the console from this point onwards. This means that if I then send a string through a `request()`, the string has `[0m` appended to it and fails to return a correctly formatted `response()`.

If I run `OSRM` from `CMD` prior to running my application in Visual Studio, I don't have this problem.

Can anybody tell me why the `[0m` might be appearing and how I can get rid of it?

Comment: [0m is the end part of an ansi colour string.. to reset back to normal..

Comment: That looks like whatever you're reading there comes from a program that thinks it's printing stuff to a terminal (emulator) and changes colours along the way. Maybe there's a command-line option to turn that off. Is the output even supposed to be program-readable or is there maybe a better way to get at the data you want?

Comment: @Joey it's sending a command to cmd.exe (which is identical to what I would manually type in and run to run `OSRM` from CMD), it shouldn't be going through anything that's altering the colour...

Comment: (a) unless you're calling cmd.exe, you're not running cmd.exe, but that's beside the point. (b) it could very well be that the process behaves differently regarding output depending on whether the output is redirected or written directly to a console window. Some programs ported from Unix-likes still use ANSI escape sequences internally and just add a wrapper that converts them to the Console APIs, which may not be there when redirecting output. Another option is that, since the console host on Windows 10 now supports ANSI escape characters, you simply don't see it normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this was `Console.ResetColor();"`